# Count of Rows Grouped by Variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to get a count of rows grouped by a certain variable using dplyr.

Example of the data below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQYqv.png)

Get a count of eunits = 0 by state.

Code that does not work:

```
data  %>% select(state, eunit) %>% filter(eunit == 0) %>% summarise(nrow(.)) %>% group_by(state)
```

Error that comes up:

> Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop)

Comment: Remove `summarise(nrow(.))` ? Typo?

Comment: just `data  %>% select(state, eunit) %>% summarise(sum(eunit == 0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reverse the order of group_by and summarise dplyr verbs. Also I'm not 100% sure that nrow(.) will work (it might, but I'm not in a placed to confirm). I typically use n() to count rows in a summarise verb.

```
data  %>% 
  select(state, eunit) %>% 
  filter(eunit == 0) %>% 
  group_by(state) %>%
  summarise(cnt = n())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by state first, then summarize and count:

```
data  %>% select(state, eunit) %>% filter(eunit == 0) %>% group_by(state) %>% summarise(n())
```